# Ultralight ~24-inch computer monitor

Tags: monitors, portable

I am looking for a ~24-inch computer monitor that is as light as possible.

The computer monitor just needs to have at least the basic features:

- 1920x1080 resolution or higher
- HDMI/DVI/VGA/USB/display port/etc. are all fine

Pricewise I don't have any hard limit: the main criteria is really the weight.

Bestbuy doesn't have any option to filter by weight.

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://qr.ae/TUhSxp
- https://redd.it/9xu713
- http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/id-3824037/ultralight-inch-computer-monitor.html#21493048

FYI, if you're interested in ultralight computer monitors because you are traveling: [What solutions exist for having two large computer screens available at each destination when traveling by plane?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/125076/1810)

Comment: It appears that weight is a not a very common filtering option particularly for monitors with such a demanding diagonal width as 24". I feel like this may be a bit too heavy but [what about something like this](https://www.amazon.com/ViewSonic-TD2230-10-Point-Monitor-DisplayPort/dp/B01LVVNHTL/ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&qid=1533193865&sr=8-1&keywords=viewsonic%2Btd2230&linkCode=sl1&tag=bestheadphonesss-20&linkId=49014b5a8cfc13d4965f4f2158e76d15&language=en_US&th=1)?

Comment: @BennettYeo Thanks, I haven't found any website where weight is a filtering option :/ Your link to `ViewSonic TD2430 24 Inch 1080p 10-Point Multi Touch Screen Monitor with HDMI and DisplayPort` looked interesting but upon checking: the information on Amazon is incorrect: the actual weight is 5.5 kg, not 5.4  pounds ->  https://www.viewsonic.com/us/catalog/product_datasheet/view/key/TD2430.html

Comment: Portable monitors should be your best bet, but the wide variety of them are designed with smaller vertical compactness at 15.6"-17". Based on the portable monitor lists I've been looking at it seem there is a weight jump between 17-20 by a nearly a factor of 3, with 24" monitors weighing at least 10 lbs. Also you are correct the Amazon spec if off, I was actually looking at the official spec sheet which says the monitor weighs 12.2 lbs (hence may be a bit too heavy). It still weighs less than a lot of the monitors with similar diagonal breath, however.

Comment: @BennettYeo Yes I had indeed high hope for [portable monitors](https://smile.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=Portable+LED+Monitor)  but they seem to be either too small or too heavy.

Comment: have you tried spud monitors ?

Comment: @rainyday thanks, the quality of the image looks very bad on the spud according to https://youtu.be/XufsrHTLNig and from what I can see in non-official demos. Also it seems sold out from the official website. But you're welcome to add it as an answer, I wasn't aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

So far the lightest monitors I have found are, ordered by increasing weight:

21.5-inch:

- [Acer S220HQL Abd 21.5-Inch Widescreen LCD Monitor](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B005LJWJSG/ref=psdc_1292115011_t4_B005Q5F7KM?th=1): DVI/VGA (no HDMI), 1920 x 1080. [Specifications](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/ET.WS0HP.A01) ([mirror](http://archive.is/6eF83)) **1.86 kg (=4.10 lbs) (unclear if it's without  or with stand)**.
- [HP 22er 21.5-inch Display](https://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/hp-22er-215-inch-display) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20181119042050/https://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/hp-22er-215-inch-display)): HDMI/VGA, 1920 x 1080 @ 60 Hz, 2.07 kg (=4.56 lbs) (without stand), **2.44 kg (=5.38 lbs) (with stand)**.

23-inch:

- [Acer S230HL 23-Inch 1080p Widescreen LED LCD Monitor (Black)](https://smile.amazon.com/Acer-S230HL-23-Inch-Widescreen-Monitor/dp/B005Q5F7KM?sa-no-redirect=1). [Specifications](https://www.cnet.com/products/acer-s230hl-abd-led-monitor-full-hd-1080p-23-umvs0aaa02/specs/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20181117061022/https://www.cnet.com/products/acer-s230hl-abd-led-monitor-full-hd-1080p-23-umvs0aaa02/specs/)):

  - Without stand - width: 21.6 in - depth: 1.3 in - height: 13.1 in - weight: 2.3 kg (=5.1 lbs)
  - With stand - width: 21.6 in - depth: 6.6 in - height: 15.1 in - weight: **2.4 kg (=5.3 lbs)**. I confirmed the weight on one such monitor I purchased.
- [AOC - 24B1H 23.6" LED FHD Monitor](https://www.bestbuy.com/site/aoc-24b1h-23-6-led-fhd-monitor-black/6257434.p?skuId=6257434) ([Amazon](https://smile.amazon.com/AOC-24B1H-Class-Monitor-Panel/dp/B07F1BRN74?sa-no-redirect=1),  [newegg](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824160346)), which weights **2.6 kg (= 5.7 lbs)**. From the [official specifications](https://eu.aoc.com/en/products/24b1h/specs) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20181104220835/https://eu.aoc.com/en/products/24b1h/specs)): "Net weight excl package kg: 2.6 Kg". It costs between 110 USD and 150 USD, signal input is (HDMI 1.4 x 1, VGA), and resolution is 1920x1080.

24-inch:

- [Sceptre E246BV-FC 24" LED HDTV Display 1920x1080 Full HD HDMI VGA USB, True Black (2017)](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B06XDJ41F5/ref=psdc_1292115011_t4_B01HIA63AU); [Specifications](http://www.sceptre.com/overview-408.html) ([mirror](http://archive.fo/s0Y7A)): HDMI/VGA, weight: **2.44 kg (=  5.39 lbs)** with stand, 2.22 kg (= 4.89 lbs) without stand. Note: has bad reviews on Amazon (3.4/5 score).
- [SCEPTRE E248W-1920R 24-inch](https://smile.amazon.com/Sceptre-E248W-1920R-Ultra-1080p-Monitor/dp/B01HIA63AU?sa-no-redirect=1): 16:9, HDMI/VGA, Blue Light filter,  weight: **2.6 kg (= 5.77 lbs)** with stand, 2.42 kg (= 5.33 lbs) 
  without stand.

---

Note that the weight information is often incorrect on Amazon. In most cases, this is due to unit errors, e.g. 5 kg in the official specifications becomes 5 lbs on Amazon. Examples of products with such issues:

- [Dell S Series S2719DM 27" Ultrathin Monitor](https://smile.amazon.com/Dell-S2719DM-27-Ultrathin-Monitor/dp/B079QRS43V?sa-no-redirect=1): advertises 8.88 lbs but instead is ~8kg. Same issue with the [Dell SE2717H](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B01MZAT8P7/ref=psdc_1292115011_t4_B00M9B3S0W) and the [Dell S2419H](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B07DD4FM8Q/ref=psdc_1292115011_t2_B079RB4Z9T).
- [Sceptre E248W-1920R 24 Inch Ultra Thin 1080p 75Hz LED Monitor HDMI VGA, Metal Black 2018](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01HIA63AU):  this Amazon page claims that the weight is 5 lbs, however the [official specifications](http://www.sceptre.com/overview-398.html) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20181117192300/http://www.sceptre.com/overview-398.html)) mention a slightly heavier weight: 5.77 lb With Stand, 5.33 lb Without Stand.
- [ViewSonic VP2771 Professional 27" 1440p Monitor USB Type C 100% sRGB Rec709 14-bit 3D](https://smile.amazon.com/ViewSonic-VP2771-Professional-Calibration-Photography/dp/B01LW8JU15?sa-no-redirect=1): this Amazon page claims that the weight is 6.8 lbs, however the [official specifications](https://www.viewsonic.com/us/vp2771.html)  ([mirror](http://archive.is/EYiXG)) mention the weight (with the stand) is 6.8 kg.

Amazon tends to reject reviews that point to those issues. As a result, when looking for weight information, one has to double check on the manufacturer's official website, which typically has  for each product one technical specification page specifying the weight.

---

I contacted the customer services of a few monitor manufacturers to ask for their lightest monitors:

- AOC (http://us.aoc.com/en/contact-sales): I'm waiting for their reply.
- Dell (https://www.dell.com/learn/us/en/uscorp1/campaigns/chat-splitter): I was told that the [Dell 24 Monitor | E2417H](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/accessories/apd/210-aiwg) (5.77 kg) is their lightest monitor.
- Spectre (http://www.sceptre.com/ -> Live Chat): I'm waiting for their reply.

Comment: If bought at Amazon the price can be [reduced to $110](https://www.amazon.com/AOC-24B1H-Class-Monitor-Panel/dp/B07F1BRN74) or [$120 at Newegg](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824160346)

Comment: The best price for your lightest monitor is [129.25 at Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01F6V6SSK/?tag=pcpapi-20). [Here is a link to track the cheapest price for the HP 22er 21.5-inch](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/D6DzK8/hp-22er-215-inch-led-backlit-monitor). Let me know if you would like me to find cheaper prices for the other minitors.

Comment: Just note that the lightweight monitors you've listed are such because they have external PSU, which means that most such monitors are relatively lightweight, without PSU, but you still got to carry the PSU around, right?

Comment: @MikhailV I believe so, and unfortunately it's typically difficult to find the weight of the power adapters. I don't have a scale with me currently and can't weight the ones I have around me.

Answer (score 1):

Physical format wise, the Asus ProArt PQ22UC can not be beaten. Slim everywhere, no bulging for connectors, slick folding stand, light weight (only 1.5 kg without stand). It is also an ~5000 USD professional 4K OLED monitor which pretty much rules it out for travel. Wish a similar monitor existed with a far cheaper panel but same package.

One of the lighest weight large screen monitor especially well suited for travel is the AOC E2351F at 2.5kg official weight total. The monitor can stand on it's "easel" and if you wish to lift it off the table and travel with the stand, you should know the tube part of the stand comes off with a single screw which is very easy to manipulate by hand -- it's not a thumbscrew it has a "flap". The base of the stand is plastic, further lowering weight. I looked far and wide and this is pretty much the only monitor doing this except for an even older slightly smaller AOC which was DisplayLink so that's garbage. This one also uses a 12V AC/DC adapter with a 5.5mmx2.5mm plug which is easy to get very lightweight variants of. Any monitor which has a C13/C14 connector is IMO too thick out of necessity to be suitable for travel, the AC/DC adapter needs to be separate to avoid the bulky connector and to make it easy to convert the plug internationally. A C7/C8 could work but for some reason I never saw any doing that.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Gechic 2101H (21.5 inch)
https://www.gechic.com/en/2101h-portable-monitor/spec/

**2.348 kg** it says, which is still quite heavy in my opinion for a portable monitor, probably because of the built-in speakers.

Another option is to buy a monitor with an external PSU, such monitors are usually
around 2-2.5 kg. But note that you still need to carry the PSU around, but of course it
is more convinient than the built-in PSU since you can distribute the weight as you wish.

For example this monitor is ca. 1.8 kg (w/o stand and PSU)
AOC Value Line 22B2H(00/01) 21.5"
https://eu.aoc.com/en/products/monitors/22b2h

And there are some others with similar weight, you just need to find a catalogue that
can filter by PSU type (external/built-in)

Comment: Thanks, agreed, at that weight we can find a larger monitor. Note that according to the website the weight doesn't seem to include the stand. But good to know this option and perhaps one day this manufacturer will make it lighter.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt that Gechic monitor does not have a classical  detachable  stand, so I think 2.4 kg includes the "stand" which is a part of the monitor, at least I believe so from the images.  As for desktop monitor you still have to count the PSU as well, I have added this to my answer.