# Portable alternatives to conventional LED monitors for coding on two large screens after traveling by plane?

Tags: displays, portable

> Clarifying note: I'm looking for device types that aren't regular computer monitors (see [this question](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/10010/40) if you're looking for a list of lightweight monitors), but could be used as such (e.g., pico projectors), or some tricks to make regular computer monitors more transportable (e.g., removing the stand).

Whenever I travel by plane, I need to have a few computer monitors as soon as possible after I arrive to my destination. I use a multi-monitor configuration (ideally at least 2 external monitors in addition to my laptop). The computer monitors should be decent enough for coding purpose, i.e. 1920x1080 resolution or higher, and somewhere between 24 and ~27 inches.

Are there any such products that can be easily transported in my luggage while traveling by plane?

---

All the solutions I found so far are not satisfying:

- All the [portable LED Monitors](https://smile.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=Portable+LED+Monitor) I found so far are too small (less than 20 inches).
- All the [multimonitors laptops](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/slidenjoy/slidenjoy-double-or-triple-your-screens) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20181103213310/https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/slidenjoy/slidenjoy-double-or-triple-your-screens)) I found have too small monitors.
- [Handheld/nano/pico/mobile/pocket projectors](https://www.amazon.com/s/?ie=UTF8&keywords=pocket+pico+projector&tag=googhydr-20&index=aps&hvadid=229042784333&hvpos=1t1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=8344212667170167954&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=b&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9031934&hvtargid=kwd-295958976894&ref=pd_sl_96ntajwyzi_b_p38) don't have a very crisp image, which makes it inconvenient to code. Furthermore, I'd need a screen to project against, which would be challenging to set up to simulate a multi-monitor configuration.
- I sometimes cannot find any business that rent computer monitors, and purchasing computer monitors each time isn't that financially efficient (if I try to resell the monitors, it takes some time and I only get ~70% money back at best, assuming I find a buyer).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85319/discussion-on-question-by-franck-dernoncourt-what-solutions-exist-for-having-two).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll summarize the comments in this answer, since comments can be removed anytime on Stack Exchange:

- [jcaron](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/30703/jcaron): remove the computer monitor stand.
- [Mike Harris](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/41096/mike-harris): one could use [coworking spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coworking).
- [David Richerby](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/11491/david-richerby), [user71659](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/67998/user71659), [Rory Alsop](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop), [Michael Hampton](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/3221/michael-hampton): there is currently no solution aside from buying/renting on site.
- [JonathanReez](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/9009/jonathanreez): buy a pair of used monitors on site.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using something like this.
These are folding / sliding screens from behind your monitor. Great for when you want to carry your laptop, but you should be able to do some serious work.

https://www.yourslide.com/ (Kickstarter)

https://www.razer.com/eu-en/project-valerie (Razer's implementation)

Comment: Project Valerie was a demo, not an actual product.

Comment: Thanks, one issue with all the multi-monitor laptops I have seen so far are that the monitors are 17.3 inch or smaller. I'd prefer at least 23 inches.