# Ultralight ~14-inch computer monitor

Tags: monitors, portable

Mirroring [Ultralight ~24-inch computer monitor](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10010/ultralight-24-inch-computer-monitorfor) at a much smaller size. The market is full of noname Chinese devices making it very hard make a tally.

I guess USB C input is a given these days, having HDMI and a separate USB C for power is optional.

To set a baseline, both the Lenovo ThinkVision M14 and the Dell P1424H is 600g.